# how to send message from one thread to fargment thread using handler

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-handler

I want to send some message from one thread to another using handler.But actually  dont know to implement it.In below code I want to send message from Broadcaster receiver class to the fragment.But I don't know how to implement this.

Fragement Scetion Code:

```
Calendar calendar= Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,16);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,42);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
Intent intent =new Intent(getContext(),NotificationActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("id",R.id.notification_imageView);
PendingIntent pendingIntent =  
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(),100,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
System.out.println("DEBUG==> Instantiating Alarm Manager Service");
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),1000 * 60 * 
02,pendingIntent);
```

BroadcastReceiever Class --ClassNotificationActivity.class

```
   public class NotificationActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {
   private View view;
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   ImageView img;
   System.out.println("DEBUG==> Page Notification Activity is being loaded");
   View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.Samplelayout, null);
   img = view.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
   System.out.println("DEBUG==> Loading bulb Image for Animation"+img);
   System.out.println("DEBUG==> Loading bulb Image for Animation");
   Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation((float) 0.5, 0); // Change alpha from fully visible to 
   invisible
   animation.setDuration(500); // duration - half a second--2 minutes
   animation.setRepeatCount(200);
   img.startAnimation(animation);
    }
      }
```

Manifest.xml

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM" />

  <receiver  android:name=".view.ui.NotificationActivity" />
```

Samplelayout.xml:

```
   <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/Dumble"
                android:tint="@android:color/white"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="32dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="32dp" />


        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `onResume()` register your BroadcastReceiver.

```
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        registerReceiver(this, IntentFilter("com.my.app.test_br"))
    }
```

In `onPause()` make sure to unregister the receiver

```
override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        unregisterReceiver(this)
    }
```

It's important to note the value I used for the `IntenFilter`. This will be how other classes will specify which broadcast receivers they are sending to.

From the class that is sending the broadcast, initialized your broadcast Intent (Note the value used for the Intent param is the same as the one used when registering the broadcast receiver)

```
    private val timerIntent = Intent(com.my.app.test_br)
```

then send the broadcast

```
sendBroadcast(timerIntent)
```

Comment: Thanks jacqueterrell for the solution.Can we implement using handler?